# How to convert a React component to Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I found this [example dropdown menu in React](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v6-f6r2sq?file=package.json), I found it simple and very good.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from "reactstrap";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle1 = this.toggle1.bind(this);
    
    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen1: false,
    };
  }
  toggle1() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dropdownOpen1: !prevState.dropdownOpen1
    }));
  }
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.setState({ dropdownOpen1: true });
  }
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({ dropdownOpen1: false });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          className="d-inline-block"
          onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
          isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen1}
          toggle={this.toggle1}
        >
          <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown1</DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem header>Submenu 1</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 1.1</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to use it in a project whose dependencies and scripts are React. But I have no idea how to start. Could someone give me a direction? Having only 1 element I believe I can give up the constructor. I saw that React used some Dropdown components from `reactstrap`, the best method would be to include them in the dependencies of a project in Next?

Comment: By checked your profile, I am pretty sure you are backend guy. BTW i am little confused on your query rather i share what i got.
1. You can use reactstrap as dependencies, there is no issue with Nextjs
2. If you use bootstrap in your project, you can use bootstrap dropdown component too by this you can reduce extra use of dependencie(here reactstrap)
3. Nowadays people use two version of navigation one for large device and one for small device like mobile, tab.
If any confusion please proceed, and If find helpful don't forget to appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, actually I am a back-end guy. That's why my difficult working with front-end lol. I really appreciate your comment. But between reactstrap dependency and bootstrap, what would you do?

Comment: Thanks! you like it. I would definitely go for one, and depends on your requirements. Two packages has in some points different use-case.

here is use bootstrap dropdown-menu  and for mobile menu use my custom drawer menu.
https://zailand-demo-landing.vercel.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class components in Next JS but most of Next JS docs use functional components, so I would recommend that you convert this class component to a functional component.

Here is a quick tutorial https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/convert-react-class-to-function-component

You can recreate the logic using React Hooks. There are ready made hooks for hovering https://usehooks.com/useHover/

Adding dependencies in NextJS is similar with React. Just import the dependencies on top of your file